# VB.NET how to populate a ComboBox in an UserControl from a Form

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have an `UserControl` where data from `MySQL` table loads in a `ComboBox` while it is loading.

```
 Private Sub LoadFeeGroup()

    Try
        OpenConnection()
        qry = "SELECT GroupId, GroupName FROM master_fee_group WHERE Stat='1' ORDER BY GroupName ASC"

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(qry, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "master_fee_group")
        With CmbGroup
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("master_fee_group")
            .DisplayMember = "GroupName"
            .ValueMember = "GroupId"
        End With
        If CmbGroup.Items.Count > 0 Then
            CmbGroup.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And this Subroutine is being called when the `UserControl` is being loaded.

```
Private Sub AdmissionFeeUc_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadFeeGroup()
End Sub
```

Now user can add any Fee Group Name (if not added previously) by opening a form.

Now I want to call this `LoadFeeGroup()` subroutine from that form so that user can see the added Fee Group Name in the `ComboBox` of the `UserControl` after closing the form.

Something like...

```
Private Sub FormFeeGroup_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    ' Code for calling the UserControl subroutine..
End Sub
```

I have tried to call the Subroutine like below,

[image: subroutine]

but failed.

How can I do that ?

**UPDATE**

I have added a button in the `UserControl`.

```
Private Sub BtnNewGroup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnNewGroup.Click
    Dim frmFeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup
    Dim dlgres As DialogResult = frmFeeGroup.ShowDialog()
    If DlgRes <> DialogResult.OK Then
        Return
    Else
        LoadFeeGroup()
    End If
End Sub
```

And in the `FormClosing` event

```
Private Sub FormFeeGroup_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If Me.DialogResult <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Return
    Else
        'nothing to do
    End If
End Sub
```

And in the `Close` button in the form,

```
Private Sub BtnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

My purpose is **Partially served**. Partially because, If I open the `Form` from the menu, the `ComboBox` is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own constructor for the form where you must pass a user control instance to it. That way you cannot create an instance of the form without specifying which user control it should be "tied" to.

For instance, put this in your form's code:

```
Public Property TargetFeeUc As AdmissionFeeUc

Public Sub New(ByVal FeeUc As AdmissionFeeUc)
    InitializeComponent() 'Must be called before anything else.

    Me.TargetFeeUc = FeeUc
End Sub
```

Then to create a new form instance you'll always be forced to give it an `AdmissionFeeUc` control.

```
'If written inside the user control's code:
Dim frmFeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup(Me)

'If written somewhere else:
Dim frmFeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup(<user control instance here>)

'...for example:
Dim frmFeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup(AdmissionFeeUc1)
```

And whenever you want to update the user control from your `FormFeeGroup` form you just need to call:

```
TargetFeeUc.LoadFeeGroup()
```

---

**EDIT:**

To get the user control instance if it was created dynamically you have to set the control's [**`Name` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx) when creating it, then you can reference it via:

```
<target control or form>.Controls("<user control name here>")

'For example:
Me.Controls("MyFeeUc")

'Or for sub-controls:
Me.Panel1.Controls("MyFeeUc")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it. It is giving me error like `AdmissionFeeUc is a type and cannot be used as an expression` while calling the form from menu `Dim FeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup(AdmissionFeeUc)`

Comment: @Raj : `AdmissionFeeUc` is the control's class. A type, just like the error says. You need to pass a control _instance_, that is, the initialized version of the control that is placed on your form. If it was created using the VS designer then unless you changed its name it should by default be called `AdmissionFeeUc#` - where `#` is a number.

Comment: @Raj : So you need to access the control by its name. The default name for the first instance is `AdmissionFeeUc1`, which is also what I wrote in my answer. If you don't know its name then select the control in the designer and scroll up to its `(Name)` property: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC687747.jpeg

Comment: @Raj : As I just said you shouldn't. You must give it the name that it has _on your form_. Known as the instance's name. -- The class's name is `AdmissionFeeUc`, but _**the control's name**_ is the name it has on your form.

Comment: Yes I am giving the `Class` name(I didn't renamed or modified it). But the same error message showing.  [http://demo.codelabtec.com/sharepic/3333.png](http://demo.codelabtec.com/sharepic/3333.png). I am calling it from my application `menu` not from the `UserControl`.

Comment: Your code is working if it is being called from the `UserControl`.....`Dim frmFeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup(Me)` but not working from anywhere else.

Comment: If I create an `UserControl` in VS, by default it's name and the class name will be same isn't it ?

Comment: @Raj : Yes, but you should check the user control's name in the _**form where you placed it**_. Not the user control itself. If you are in the user control's designer then yet again you have no instance.

Comment: @Raj : Check the name through the _**form's designer**_, not the user control designer. I uploaded two images for clarity: http://imgur.com/a/oQDZs

Comment: See the link and tell me where and which should I rename. [http://demo.codelabtec.com/sharepic/334.png](http://demo.codelabtec.com/sharepic/334.png). I have tried renaming the Name Property, but the class name automatically renames. I have tried renaming the filename, but the error resumes.

Comment: @Raj : I misinterpreted you previous comment, sorry for that. At this point you don't need to rename anything. See my latest comment instead. -- The difference between the form's designer and the user control's designer is that in the form's designer you have created an _instance_ of the user control. Whereas in the user control designer you are modifying the class directly.

Comment: I tried, but the class name of the form also be changed automatically. Therefore I cannot use `Dim frmFeeGroup As New FormFeeGroup(<user control instance here>)`. Please elaborate it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Raj : Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140235/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-raj).

Comment: @Raj : I have updated the answer. Did you solve the SQL confict? If not you might want to ask a question about it later... I've never dealt with such conflicts before.